# Поиск подстроки в начале QString

Tags: c++, qt

Как найти подстроку в начале строки, и убрать чувствительность к регистру?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть отличная функция [`StartsWith`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#startsWith) которая решает сразу первую половину вопроса. У нее есть второй параметр `Qt::CaseInsensitive`, который решает вопрос полностью.